# Pass rendered page from Selenium to Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I would like to scrape Javascript pages that require log-in. I was wondering whether it is possible to load and log-in into the page with Selenium which then passes one the rendered code to Scrapy for data extraction.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from seleniumrequests import Firefox,Chrome
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class ContractSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "contracts"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://adactmedical.com/tpd'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def __init__(self):
        driver = Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/Matija/Dropbox/Programing/Scraping/geckodriver.exe')

        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    @staticmethod
    def get__response(url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        return self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

    def parse(self, response):
        selenium_response = Selector(text=self.get_selenium_response(response.url))
        print(selenium_response)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JavaScript to do this but it can be done easily.

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
print html
```

Comment: This is great. Do you know how could I pass it to Scrapy? I've tried equaling start_urls = html[0] to no avail.

Comment: `driver.page_source` does the same thing in a simpler fashion IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Scrapy is a framework in which you can use packages like `Selenium, Beautiful Soup` etc. In your case after moving to the login page, make the login requests using selenium (Because it's a dynamic script page). then use the page response as a scrappy response. (Check for response type).

Scrapy has tools to handle the dynamic requests, try scraping with splash. Also, check for API, in the particular site.

Eg: Scrapy formats from selenium response

```
doc= HtmlXPathSelector(self.driver.page_source)
listitems = doc.select("//div[@class='test']")
```

Or try direct selenium methods.

```
next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="test"]')
```

Also, you can try

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
response = HtmlResponse(url="test url", body='response.text', encoding='utf-8')
response.xpath('//div[@class="test"]/text()')
```

Comment: Do you know how to set selenium response so that Scrapy can use it to scrape the page? I've used `driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")` as shown above but I have troubles passing the content to Scrapy. Thanks

Comment: You can convert selenium response to different response formats that scrapy can use. Check the updated answer.